# Have an item stick to the bottom of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a vertically scrollable list using a RecyclerView. The layout I'm trying to implement is that when you scroll down far enough and reach a specific item, if you keep scrolling past this item it will stick to the bottom of the screen while the rest of the list continues to scroll behind it. Currently it's implemented by having a scroll listener on the RecyclerView and manually adjusting the position of the sticky view as required, but this is hacky and hard to build on.

Is there an easier way to have this kind of layout? I am currently investigating using a [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) but I'm not sure if it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have done something similar before. Sounds like you could do this in onBindViewHolder with the position and getItemViewType - i.e., when you scroll past position X where that item is, every onBind call after will check "Are we past position X? && is this position the last position?" if so, return a viewtype that is the item you want to show, else return a normal one

Comment: @SaikCaskey I don't think that would give the flexibility of having items partially scrolled behind the sticky view. As in, if the view itself is still just an element in the list, you can't scroll the next item of the list halfway past the sticky view.

Comment: You should experiment and see - there is logic built in to handle half-scrolled views. Failing that, perhaps you should do your own implementation of RecyclerView and build in a sticky view? I'm sure something on GitHub can help you get started, and you're already dealing with the low level.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I thought you wanted to keep it as part of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a CoordinatorLayout with a custom behaviour. The behaviour should be applied to the sticky view and make it appear/disappear as the RecyclerView scrolls. You have to override `onStartNestedScroll` in your behaviour to return `true` to receive calls for scroll changes.

Comment: @Rahul I don't have access to it anymore, this was done at a previous internship.

Comment: @Rahul Which part exactly? I wrote the code myself, but it was a while ago. If it's about the behaviour itself, it continuously updated the position of the view manually. I think there are a few examples you can find online of that part. The main issue I had was not knowing to return true in `onStartNestedScroll`.

Comment: onStartNestedScroll returns true then where I have to handle scroll?

Comment: @Rahul I think it was in onTouch in the behaviour (check for scroll events): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html